# How to update Django query object in a for loop

Tags: django

I know you can update all Django records matching a filter by using:

```
myQuery = myModel.objects.filter(fieldA = 1, FieldB = 2)
myQuery.update(fieldA = 5, FieldB = 6)
```

But if I want to iterate through the query results and only update certain values, how can I do this?
I have tried:

```
myQuery = myModel.objects.filter(fieldA = 1, FieldB = 2)
for item in range(myQuery.count())
    if (myQuery[item].fieldC) == 10:
        myQuery[item].update(fieldC = 100)
```

This returns `AttributeError: 'myModel' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: Why not add `fieldC=10` to the filter condition?

Comment: Ah yes, that does make a lot more sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out yourself, a `Model` object has no `.update(..)` method. You can [**`.save(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) the object, and specify what fields to update with the [**`update_fields=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save):

```
myQuery = myModel.objects.filter(fieldA=1, FieldB=2)
for item in myQuery:
    if item.fieldC == 10:
        item.fieldC = 100
        item.save(update_fields=['fieldC'])
```

That being said, the above is ***very* inefficient**. Since for *n* objects, it will make a total of at most *n+1* queries.

You can simply move the condition to the filter part here:

```
myModel.objects.filter(fieldA=1, FieldB=2, fieldC=10).update(fieldC=100)
```

Comment: I have a field with the number of seconds and I want to update that to hh:mm:ss. I can't use the sufficient way you mentioned in the second month because it will not be the same for every object is there any other way to avoid the time it is taking to update the thousands of objects?

Comment: @Lord-shiv: can you ask a new question? Please include sample data, the models and what you try to achieve.